# I am trying to code movement in unity and I keep getting this error and I don't know what it means

Tags: unity-game-engine, invalidoperationexception

This is the error I get in the output and I've been trying to diagnose the issue for an hour now, I'm new to unity so this is kind of confusing to me.

[The error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/our5F.png)

[This is the code I'm using, following a brackeys tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A28TN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project may be set to **New Input System**. From the Edit menu, go to project setting and in the player section, change the **Active Input Handling** to `Both`.

[image]

[image]